# Python .count: Can't find correct syntax to count \n

Tags: python, string, list, python-2.5

To start I will mention that I am new to the Python Language and come from a networking background. If you are wondering why I am using Python 2.5 it is due to some device constraints.

What I am trying to do is count the number of lines that are in a string of data as seen below. (not in a file)

```
data = ['This','is','some','test','data','\nThis','is','some','test','data','\nThis','is','some','test','data','\nThis','is','some','test','data','\n']
```

Unfortunately I can't seem to get the correct syntax to count **\n**. So far this is what I have come up with.

```
num = data.count('\n')
print num
```

The above code is clearly wrong for the intended output since it returns 1 in relation to the test data, I would like to see it return 4 if possible. It only finds 1 of the '\n' being the last one in the example since it matches.

If I use the following code instead to find all of them it doesn't run due to syntax.

```
num = data.count (\n)
print num
```

I based this code from the following link, the example is the third one down.

http://anh.cs.luc.edu/python/hands-on/3.1/handsonHtml/strings3.html

Is there anyway of accomplishing this or should I be looking at a different solution?

Any help is appreciated
Thank-you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`list.count` is used to get the count of an item in list, but you need to do a substring search in each item to get the count as 4.

```
>>> data = ['This','is','some','test','data','\nThis','is','some','test','data','\nThis','is','some','test','data','\nThis','is','some','test','data','\n']
```

Total number of items that contain `'\n'`:

```
>>> sum('\n' in item for item in data)
4
```

Sum of count of  all `'\n'`s in `data`:

```
>>> data = ['\n\nfoo','\n\n\nbar']
>>> sum(item.count('\n') for item in data)
5
```

Comment: Both of these fail when an item contains more than one `'\n'`. `item.count('\n')` instead of `1`?

Comment: @Brian Use: `sum(item.count('\n') for item in data)` for that.
`

Comment: Just wanted to make sure OP was aware of that. +1

Comment: Brian's code works: num = sum(item.count('\n') for item in data), print num, '\n' = 4. Thank-you Ashwini, & Brian

Answer (score 1):

Your first code does not work because you only have one `'\n'` in your actual list of strings. When you compare `'\n'` to something like `'nThis'`, then it will say that `\n` is not equal to that string and not include it in the count.

What you can do is join the list into a string like so:

```
x = ''.join(num)
```

and then try using the `count` method of the string class. This will let you find substrings that are equivalent to '\n' in the total string.

```
y = x.count('\n')
print y
```